# Laravel Deeper Validation for Review System (User may react after 5 consecutive login days)

Tags: laravel, validation, authorization, forum

I'm making a forum with laravel atm.
Like the title says, I want a custom validation rule which makes it possible for the user to create threads on the forum but only after 5 consecutive days of logging in. I'm not sure where to start though. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 new columns on the users table

```
$table->timestamp('last_login_at');
$table->integrer('login_days');
```

Then register a listener on the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` Event to check if the last login was more than one day ago and increment it if so and update the last_login_at field to `now()`

Then on your model create a function

```
public function loggedInMoreThanFiveDays()
{
   return $this->login_days >= 5;
}
```

Then you can do an if statement

```
if($user->loggedInMoreThanFiveDays()) { ... do code here}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is just one option, there are probably other ways to do this, depends on your use case

Comment: Thanks i'll try this!